# Do different Pals need different foods?

Tags: palworld

I currently have about 10 different Pals working at my base. I have several berry farms and Chikipis producing eggs. At this point I have hundreds of berries and eggs in my feed boxes, and none of my Pals seem unhappy currently, so the food seems to work for them.

However, I can make tons of different types of food, and when I had a Cattiva working in my base, it was constantly unhappy. Do I need different types of food for different Pals, or can I continue to shovel berries into the feed boxes?

Comment: Cattiva is a miner and I noticed they get sad all the time. I think miners are just prone to getting all messed up in the heads.

Answer (score 4):

Different pals don't have different diets, but they *do* vary in terms of stomach-size! (Daedream, for instance, has a nutrition meter that goes up to 225)

So the different types of food aren't to satisfy different diets, but because the more complex foods are more filling. In short, they don't *need* different types of food, but if the choice is between shoving 5 plates of berries or 1 Chikipi Skewer down your Pengullet -- one of those is simply more efficient.

Higher level foods also provide SAN recovery -- plain Red Berries do not. If you want to keep your Pals healthy, mentally, nicer food goes a long way!